# Inferring the ReturnType<> of a chained function

Tags: typescript, twilio, type-inference, twilio-node

I'm working with the `twilio-node` pkg and there's the [`fetch` function](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/lib/rest/lookups/v1/phoneNumber.d.ts#L120):

```js
lookupResponse = await twilioClient.lookups.v1.phoneNumbers('+123').fetch({type: 'carrier'});
```

with a clearly defined return type, [`Promise<PhoneNumberInstance>`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/2b5365baba8e099227282a5b45fbf9c56b4d4019/lib/rest/lookups/v1/phoneNumber.d.ts#L100). Since I'm initializing the `lookupResponse` beforehand, I'd like to extract / infer the function's return type straightaway.

Now, I already know how to unwrap a promise's type:

```js
export type ThenArg<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? U : T;
```

But how do I specify the argument of the previously chained `phoneNumbers` function?
Trying this:

```js
let lookupResponse: ThenArg<
  ReturnType<typeof twilioClient.lookups.v1.phoneNumbers.fetch>
>;
```

throws `Property 'fetch' does not exist on type 'PhoneNumberListInstance'`.

What do I need to pass here?

```js
let lookupResponse: ThenArg<
   ReturnType<typeof twilioClient.lookups.v1.phoneNumbers.???.fetch>
//                                                        ^^^            
>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about Twilio so apologies in advance if I steer you the wrong way, but based on your code, `phoneNumbers` is a function, not just a property. So you need the return type of the `fetch` function that's on the return type of `twilioClient.lookups.v1.phoneNumbers`. Something like:

```typescript
type LookupResponseType = ThenArg<
    ReturnType<
        ReturnType<
            typeof twilioClient["lookups"]["v1"]["phoneNumbers"]
        >["fetch"]
    >
>;
```

[Playground link with mockup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkHsGMGsFoCuAHAUNSA7AzgF1LgO4CWANsZAMLkCmm+AvKAN6qiimSSwrYBcLNu1AA3AIwDWw4cgAWWGgDlEAWwBGNAE7YAFAEpB06Zpq5EmzIaPSAZqeiz9V68dPnLABU2QVxbDQA6E2xIUhEaHQAWACY9AG4hF1AAX0SjZITrVOlslNQM1FRcAE9kGlAAFVk6AEFNAHMAHgqAPlAmCtAaAA9cOgATbFAvHz8aABliWBpG4kw7TVAAVTaAfmXQAQqEotLy8a4eZAAlGmxkLH8KvfbK6sw6prTTswtrssa06Rf3d5mvlwlMqQGwEEjkKi0egAbQARJxuLxYQBdOHiFFwuQKZTqLTYFEA9gtOF2XAOAnSFqoFpxIA)

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! One adjustment -- `'twilioClient' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here` so I needed to add prepend `typeof` to it. I'll update your answer if you don't mind.